# What happens to reputation gained during suspension?

Tags: discussion, reputation

There's this infamous user whose account is suspended for the next 3 years still, so his reputation shows as "1". I was wondering about 2 things:

1. Does he get his old reputation back when suspension ends?
2. Does he get the reputation he got during suspension added when suspension ends?

(I for one am for "no" to both questions, so that he has to start again at 1 in July 2016, provided his suspension isn't prolonged.)

Comment: It should not be possible to earn rep while suspended (although "our special friend" seems to have found ways to do that).

Comment: @ThePhoton: I agree. But it's not just Hypertroll's fake accounts, he also gets rep on his regular account for older answers.

Comment: @GeertGoeteyn, you can't single out a single person and clear their rep, it isn't fair. Would you prefer that all users who get suspended get their rep wiped?

Comment: @trav1s Yes. Makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Technically yes, but I seriously doubt there will be an end to the behaviour that caused the suspension.

Comment: Time cures everything :-)

Comment: @Anindo: That's what they say, but TS is an exception. After some time delta t his suspension gets prolongued by a time T > delta t :)

Comment: If suspension time grows geometrically with number of infractions, his suspension time should already extend beyond the probable end of life on Earth.

Answer (score 1):

Reputation is recalculated and all rep that would have been gained during the suspension is awarded when the suspension ends.

See this Stack Exchange Blog post: [A Day in the Penalty Box](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)

Comment: I'm not saying all rep should be permanently wiped upon suspension, but I also think no rep should be gained during suspension. (As usual for meta the -1 means disagree)

Comment: @radagast: My answer describes the way the system currently works.